# HTML: How to remove space between divs?

Tags: html, css

I have a big square div
I need to show 4 small squares inside it separated in 2 rows 
 i do it like this

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#main>div>div {
  width: 46px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="line">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/dimoff66/pen/oNNLYjx?editors=0111

but i cant get what is the nature of space between 1 and 2, and between 3 and 4
if i make width of small square more they shift to the next line

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The space is due to your `display:inline-block` property that reads the newline between the two inner divs as a space.

Just remove the newline (like this `<div>1</div><div>2</div>`) and you will be fine.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#main>div>div {
  width: 48px;
  /** 48px + 1px + 1px = 50px */
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="line">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <div>3</div><div>4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: NOTE: The removal of newline in `<div>3</div><div>4</div>`. That prevents the divs from appearing in different lines.

Comment: @mrid, your note is the answer, thanx

Comment: I have update the answer